# why does a (JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)) occur while trying to load stream in DeepFace?

Tags: json, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to stream deepface from webcam but I keep on getting this error after running this command

DeepFace.stream('desktop/deepf/my_dataset')

```
 vgg_face_weights.h5 will be downloaded...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 735, 
        in stream
        , source = source, time_threshold = time_threshold, frame_threshold = frame_threshold)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\deepface\commons\realtime.py", line 41, in analysis
        model = DeepFace.build_model(model_name)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 46, in build_model
        model = model()
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\deepface\basemodels\VGGFace.py", line 77, in loadModel
        gdown.download(url, output, quiet=False)
      File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\gdown\download.py", line 97, in download
        cookies = json.load(f)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deepface downloads pretrained weights from google drive but sometimes it exceeds the daily download limit. In this case, download the pre-trained weights from this url manually: https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CPSeum3HpopfomUEK1gybeuIVoeJT_Eo

Then, copy it to the HOME_FOLDER/.deepface/weights folder.